# Getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) while trying to read big numbers

Tags: segmentation-fault, cs50

## Trying to read big numbers and checking them with isalpha and been getting this error with really big number (in c)

When I try it with 555555 for example it works
but when I try with 4003600000000014 Segmentation fault (core dumped) pops out
how do I fix this ?

```
int main(void)
{
    int digit;
    long number;
    int length = 0;

    do
    {
        number = get_long("Number: ");
    }
    while(isalpha(number) > 0 || number < 0);

    while(number)
    {
        digit = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        length++;
    }

    printf("length is: %i\n", length);

}
```

Does someone know how to get over this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segmentation fault comes here `isalpha(number)` because `isalpha` takes a `char` as an argument. [Here is the man page.](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha)